# Button onClick Call Java Method Until Certain Result

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, jsp, controller

I'm completely new to the Spring framework (and most web development in general), but I'm trying to hook up some heavy Java backend code to a new Spring and JSP project. My Controller's `handleRequest()` is kicking off a long running worker thread before it returns my request.jsp `ModelAndView` object. After that I'd like to be able to still interface with this Controller from my JSP form to be able to call `isThreadDone()` in the Controller whenever a button in the form is clicked. Based on three different results, I then redirect accordingly. Is this possible with my current approach? This seems to violate some of the Spring MVC approach, but I can't think of a good way to do this that I can wrap my head around. If anything is way off here, please excuse my ignorance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Spring `@Async` annotation.  If you annotate a Service-layer bean with that annotation, it then runs in its own thread, allowing your Controller thread to run without interruption after calling the Service method.  Have that thread is set a value held at the Class level for the Service via `synchronous` methods, and your Controller code can just check those toggles at will to see if the process is done or not.  Something like:

```
@Service
public myServiceClass {
   private boolean isDone = false;
   public synchronized void setIsDone(boolean isDone) {
      isDone = isDone;
   }
   public synchronized boolean getIsDone() {
      return isDone;
   }
   @Async
   public void myServiceMethod() {
      ...long-running stuff...
      setIsDone(true);
   }
```

In the Controller:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
   @RequestMapping
   public kickOffHandlerMethod() {
      myServiceClass.myServiceMethod();
      }
   }
   @RequestMapping
   public dependentHandlerMethod() {
      if(myServiceClass.getIsDone()) {
         ...do something...
      }
   }
}
```

If more than one request might kick off the process, then I would save each `isDone` toggle in a HashMap with some kind of identifier.  Then the threads would update individual toggles, one for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Well, anything is possible, right? Based on what you've provided, you can just keep a reference to the thread--maybe in the HttpSession--so that when a new request comes in from clicking the button, you can query it and return an appropriate response.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seems like a workaround rather than a solution. If that's the best way though, then that's the best way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matt: What concerns you about it? If you define your scenario a little more clearly, maybe a more appropriate solution will appear.